# Python ctypes and mutable strings calling Fortran DLL: Access Violation Error

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes

I am trying call a subroutine in a Fortran DLL that requires  3 mutable strings passed to it. The subroutine is of the form:

```
Subroutine Getinfo(string_1, string_2, string_3, index)
char *60 string_1, string_2
char *30 string_3

string_1 = "String 1 return value"
string_2 = "String 2 return value"
string_3 = "String 3 return value"

end subroutine
```

Im calling the function in python as follows:

```py
dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('library.dll')
funcprot = getattr(dll, 'Getinfo')
funcprot.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_long, 
     ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_long, ctypes.c_long]

string_1 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(60)
string_2 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(60)
string_3 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(30)

funcprot(string_1, 60, string_2, 60, string_3, 30, 701)
```

I get the following error.

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x000002BD
```

I tried suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539149/access-violation-using-python-ctypes?rq=1), but it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: See my comment on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703182). Try it as `funcprot(string_1, string_2, string_3, 2, 60, 60, 30)`, i.e. append the lengths.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out as an alternative.

I think I figured out the reason for the error. It was because I passed the last parameter `index` by value and not as reference.

Changing `funcprot(string_1, 60, string_2, 60, string_3, 30, 2)` to `funcprot(string_1, 60, string_2, 60, string_3, 30, ctypes.byref(2))` fixed the issue.

I keep forgetting that in Fortran, most everything is a pointer!

Comment: Right, but I don't see why it would access 0x2BD (701) in this case. Anyway, if possible you should export a platform [C ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_interopc.htm). Otherwise these ABI issues will drive you bonkers.

Comment: Possibly because the index value that I was trying to pass was 701. And it got interpreted as the address.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "export a platform C ABI? "

Comment: OK, you showed an index value of 2, and I assumed the exception was from that particular call. For the ABI, I linked to the Intel documentation on adding a C binding. Look at the "C Calling Fortran" example. I say "platform" because C calling conventions aren't the same on Windows vs Linux, for example, but ctypes handles that.

Comment: I fixed the index value in the question to clarify.

Comment: The subroutine you show cannot compile, what code you really try?